# Nested react-router Switch

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Trying to nest a switch in my dash component, as documented [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting).

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';

<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path='/dash' component={Dashboard} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Dashboard.js

```
import { Route, Switch, useRouteMatch } from 'react-router';
import Chats from '../chats/Chats';
import DashNav from './dash-nav/DashNav';
import Contacts from '../contacts/Contacts';

const Dashboard = () => {
  let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <div>
        <DashNav url={url} />

        <Switch>
            <PrivateRoute path={path} component={Chats} />
            <PrivateRoute path={`${path}/contacts`} component={Contacts} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
    );
};
```

DashNav with the url passed as props.

```
<div>
    <Link to={`${url}/contacts`}>Contacts</Link>
</div>
```

I want to click on the link from DashNav and render {Contacts} instead of {Chats}, but it navigates to the correct url ('baseurl/dash/contacts') and renders {NotFound} with no {DashNav}.

Can anyone see why it's not working?

Comment: what is the url defined as in DashNav?

Comment: console logs '/dash'

Answer (score 0):

In the parent Router (App.js):

```
<PrivateRoute> exact path='/dash' component={Dashboard} />
```

should not have 'exact' as an attribute, and should instead be:

```
<PrivateRoute> path='/dash' component={Dashboard} />
```